# Hash table implementation in C for a simple table record

Tags: performance, algorithm, c, hash-map

I have a requirement to implement this simple table from one of the DVB S2X standards. The table is relatively small that contains no more than 28 rows. I need to use the key for the table as the second column from the structure below i.e. the `kbch` value.

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    float ldpcCodeId;
    unsigned int kbch;
    unsigned int kldpc;
    unsigned char tErrCorrection;
} dvbS2xRecord;
```

I tried to use some complex hashing algorithms on this 5 digit positive integer to create a hash that I can use an index for my array. I realized that size 28 is a much smaller value for any hashing algorithm to create a hash index without creating any collisions. I tried using `key % arrSize` which didn't perform as expected.

So I created a simple version of the hash table that can lookup in O(1), by creating a static mapping of the integer with the index in the array. The full version of the code is

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    float ldpcCodeId;
    unsigned int kbch;
    unsigned int kldpc;
    unsigned char tErrCorrection;
}dvbS2xRecord;

static const dvbS2xRecord dvbS2xRecordTable[28] = { { .22 ,  14208,  14400,   12 },
                                                    { .25 ,  16008,  16200,   12 },
                                                    { .28 ,  18528,  18720,   12 },
                                                    { .33 ,  21408,  21600,   12 },
                                                    { .4  ,  25728,  25920,   12 },
                                                    { .45 ,  28968,  29160,   12 },
                                                    { .5  ,  32208,  32400,   12 },
                                                    { .53 ,  34368,  34560,   12 },
                                                    { .55 ,  35448,  35640,   12 },
                                                    { .555,  35808,  36000,   12 },
                                                    { .57 ,  37248,  37440,   12 },
                                                    { .6  ,  38688,  38880,   12 },
                                                    { .62 ,  40128,  40320,   12 },
                                                    { .63 ,  41208,  41400,   12 },
                                                    { .64 ,  41568,  41760,   12 },
                                                    { .66 ,  43008,  43200,   12 },
                                                    { .68 ,  44448,  44640,   12 },
                                                    { .69 ,  44808,  45000,   12 },
                                                    { .71 ,  45888,  46080,   12 },
                                                    { .72 ,  46608,  46800,   12 },
                                                    { .73 ,  47328,  47520,   12 },
                                                    { .75 ,  48408,  48600,   12 },
                                                    { .77 ,  50208,  50400,   12 },
                                                    { .8  ,  51648,  51840,   12 },
                                                    { .83 ,  53840,  54000,   10 },
                                                    { .85 ,  55248,  55440,   12 },
                                                    { .88 ,  57472,  57600,   8  },
                                                    { .9  ,  58192,  58320,   8  },
                                                 };

unsigned char hashOf(unsigned int kbch);

inline unsigned char hashOf(unsigned int kbch)
{
    unsigned char idx = 0;

    switch(kbch) {
        case 14208: idx =  0 ; break; case 16008: idx =  1 ; break; case 18528: idx =  2 ; break; case 21408: idx =  3 ; break;
        case 25728: idx =  4 ; break; case 28968: idx =  5 ; break; case 32208: idx =  6 ; break; case 34368: idx =  7 ; break;
        case 35448: idx =  8 ; break; case 35808: idx =  9 ; break; case 37248: idx = 10 ; break; case 38688: idx = 11 ; break;
        case 40128: idx = 12 ; break; case 41208: idx = 13 ; break; case 41568: idx = 14 ; break; case 43008: idx = 15 ; break;
        case 44448: idx = 16 ; break; case 44808: idx = 17 ; break; case 45888: idx = 18 ; break; case 46608: idx = 19 ; break;
        case 47328: idx = 20 ; break; case 48408: idx = 21 ; break; case 50208: idx = 22 ; break; case 51648: idx = 23 ; break;
        case 53840: idx = 24 ; break; case 55248: idx = 25 ; break; case 57472: idx = 26 ; break; case 58192: idx = 27 ; break;
        default: break ;
    }
    return idx;
}

int main() 
{
    for (int i=0; i< 28; i++) {
        printf("value:%d hash:%d\n", dvbS2xRecordTable[i].kbch, hashOf( dvbS2xRecordTable[i].kbch ) );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I made the function `inline` to make the frequent access to lookup the index a bit faster. With this logic e.g. for looking up a record information for a particular `kbch` value

```
 unsigned int kbch = 50208;
 printf( "%d %0.3f %d\n", dvbS2xRecordTable[hashOf(kbch)].kldpc, \
                          dvbS2xRecordTable[hashOf(kbch)].ldpcCodeId, \
                          dvbS2xRecordTable[hashOf(kbch)].tErrCorrection );
```

The code is compiled with `gcc 4.8.5` on Centos 7 without any warnings or errors

```
 gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors hashTable.c
```

How can I further improve this hashing and/or loopkup algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

## Use a perfect hash function

What you want is to implement a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). This is any function that for any of the valid input values, results in a unique value into to the hash table. Despite the name, there is more than one way to make such a function. Also, it's easier to make if you allow the hash table to be bigger than the number of valid items. There are tools available that, given a set of inputs, can create a perfect hash function for you. One example is [GNU gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html), unfortunately it expects the set of inputs to be strings.

Another option is to find try to find a suitable mapping yourself. For example, the smallest difference between two values of kbch is 360, and the minimum value is 14208. So a possible perfect (but not minimal) hash function is:

```
unsigned int hashOf(unsigned int kbcd) {
    return (kcbd - 14208) / 360;
}
```

The maximum output value of this function is 122, so you have to make an array of 123 elements, even though only 28 elements will have a useful entry.

28 possible values is a small number, so writing something by hand might outperform a function generated by a generic tool. If you want to know what is faster, benchmark your code.

## Don't use `__attribute__((packed))` unless you really need strict packing

Why is `dvbS2xRecord` packed? You may think this is faster because it might use fewer cache lines for `dvbS2xRecordTable[]`, but now the CPU has to do unaligned reads from the `dvbS2xRecord`s, which might slow things down, or result in undefined behavior on CPU architectures that do not support unaligned access.

Comment: I did look at some implementations of the perfect hash function but I just can’t figure out the last step, to generate an index for the 28 length array. Can you show an example if possible?

Comment: You run `hashOf()` on all the possible values for kbch in order, and then you get a set of numbers. Either you have to manually arrange the array such that the first possible value of kbch is at place `hashOf(14208)` in the array, or if you can rely on GCC, write the elements of the array in the original order, but prepend `[hash] = ` to each line, where `hash` is the output of `hashOf()` for the value of `kbch` in that line. Tools like gperf can output the array in the right order for you.

Answer (score 1):

### Use `int main(void)`

C17::6.11.6:

> Function declarators The use of function declarators with empty
>   parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an
>   obsolescent feature.